# Codesign verify returns invalid argument

Tags: xcode, macos, codesign

I have an app that was signed on my build server (without errors). Apparently something went wrong and when I open it in Finder I get a message that the app is damaged.

The problem is, when I do

`codesign --verify --verbose MyApp.app`

I get

`MyApp.app: Invalid argument`

It works with any other App from Applications folder. I would expect to get a more detailed error on how the signature is broken.

Is there any option to get more details? What could cause that behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get more detailed information by using the verbose flag like this to increase the level of verbosity:

```
codesign --verify --verbose=4
codesign --verify -vvvv
codesign -v -vvvv
```

These are all the same command, just different ways of inputting it:

> -v, --verbose
>            Sets (with a numeric value) or increments the verbosity level of output. Without the verbose
>            option, no output is produced upon success, in the classic UNIX style.  If no other options
>            request a different action, the first -v encountered will be interpreted as --verify instead
>            (and does not increase verbosity).

Apple considers this a 'bug' according to their [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html):

The dual meaning of the -v option, indicating either verbosity or verification, confuses
 some people. If you find it confusing, use the unambiguous long forms --verbose and
 --verify instead.

There are also some free utilities available such as [Codesign Checker](https://www.macupdate.com/download/29706/fetch?id=software%3amisc%3acscheck&cache=cache&media=software%3amisc%3acodesignchecker.zip), that might be useful.

Comment: Thanks. That indeed gives more details. However, I still don't know what's wrong with my signature. I still get an invalid argument error:
`--validated:/Users/me/MyApp.com/Contents/Frameworks/Crashlytics.framework/Versions/Current/.

--validated:/Users/me/MyApp.com/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/Current/.

MyApp.app: Invalid argument`

Comment: @codingFriend1, How are you codesigning your app (through XCode, command-line?), and what type of certificate and entitlements do you have associated with it?

Comment: I use the command line with a Developer ID Certificate. I assume the problem is that there are various frameworks inside the app as well as a helper app. I sign each separately from 'inside out'. Maybe that is the wrong way – but it worked before...

Comment: @codingFriend1, Building the frameworks first is the correct way, so it's likely something else. What is the codesign command you use to sign everything? I have a script for my frameworks and app that basically has `xcodebuild -alltargets -configuration "Release" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY}"` for each item. I think the key to figuring out what the cause is will be checking your build log and looking at what the codesign process is doing.

Answer (score 5):

@l'L'l 's answer was correct concerning how to get more detailed logs so I accepted it.

However, for the reference, the real problem was the zip command. On my build server I zip the built app bundle. Yet I used the `zip` command line tool to do so, which does not handle aliases correctly. So when you have frameworks in your bundle they ususally have aliases pointing to the current binary version and headers. When you zip this with `zip -r` these aliases will be resolved. Then of course the code signature is no longer valid.

The correct way to zip files on Mac is to use the `ditto` command:

```
ditto -c -k --keepParent --sequesterRsrc "my source file" "myArchive.zip"
```

The same is true for the `cp` copy command. `cp -r` will expand alias files. The correct copy command is `cp -R`

---

It had always worked before with the 'wrong' commands. I guess something was changed in OS X 10.9.1 either with the comamnd line tools or with the signature validation...

Comment: I think it was changed in 10.9.0 since that's when I started seeing the problem.  I'm amazed that more people aren't having this problem.